# Multiple/series of groups in one result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm changing a number in a where clause to get the next result set. Specifically
`s.[round_roundNumber] = 1 and r.round_roundNumber = 1`
**I would like results from round 1 to 21. Can I do this in one query?**

This is my current query:

```
select
  r.match_homeTeam_abbr,
  r.match_awayTeam_abbr,
  r.round_roundNumber,
  [teamId],
  providerId,
  sum([goals]) as goals 
from [afl].[dbo].[player_stats] s
inner join [afl].[dbo].[results] r on s.[teamId] = r.[match_homeTeamId]
or s.[teamId] = r.[match_awayTeamId]
where YEAR(utcStartTime) = 2023
and YEAR(r.match_utcStartTime) = 2023
and s.[round_roundNumber] = 1
and r.round_roundNumber = 1
group by [providerId],[teamId],r.match_homeTeam_abbr,r.match_awayTeam_abbr, r.round_roundNumber
```

I think i've got it - remove join to outer select:

```
select (CASE 
          WHEN [teamId] = match_homeTeamId THEN match_homeTeam_abbr
          WHEN [teamId] = match_awayTeamId THEN match_awayTeam_abbr
        END) as team_abbr,
        round_roundNumber,
        YEAR(match_utcStartTime) as season,
        r.*
from
(
    select      
        [teamId],
        providerId,
        sum([goals]) as goals
    from [afl].[dbo].[player_stats] 
    where YEAR(utcStartTime) = 2023
    group by [providerId],[teamId]
) r
inner join [afl].[dbo].results on r.providerId = results.match_matchId
```

Comment: Thanks Dale, are my updates sufficient?